# Managing installed versions of python before pyenv was installed

Tags: python, powershell, version, pyenv

I'm new to Python and pyenv, I installed python 3.6.8 before installing pyenv, but when I type

```
pyenv versions
```

onto the powershell the output is 3.12.0, a version i did install with pyenv, but the 3.6.8 version does not come up, only the ones I installed with pyenv.

should I uninstall python 3.6.8 and re-install it with pyenv, or is there a way to add it to the versions list?

there is not a lot of documentation around the usage after installation, so i don't know really how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you downloaded Python 3.8.6, it will (probably) appear in one of the folders listed in the PATH variable. For this reason, you can (probably) use the 3.8.6 version from the terminal. Try, for example, to create a virtual environment in the current folder using `python3.8 -m venv venv` and write back later what you got as a result.

EDIT. I wrote about terminal (Mac, Linux) not about Powershell so it may differ but check anyway.

Comment: i wrote the command but nothing happened.
What I'm looking for though, is to add the 3.6 version (installed with an .exe) to the versions list in pyenv,

Comment: I meant you should already be able to use your python 3.8.6.
If you want to add it to pyenv it is better to delete your downloaded 3.8 (to avoid any conflicts) and install it via pyenv.